# How can I launch fzf inside vim and open the selected file on a split window?

Tags: vim, fzf

How can I launch `fzf` inside `vim` and open the selected file on a split window? I don't want to install any plugin.

I tried

```
:!a=$(ls | fzf) && vsplit $a
```

Comment: Are you using vim or neovim? Because if you are using neovim it would be possible. With normal vim as far as I know without a plugin it is impossible.

Comment: I'm using vim. I didn't try neovim. You say it could be possible do it in neovim. how? thanks for answering btw.

Comment: Interesting question. The problem is that fzf is sending output to stdout the whole time but you want to get just the result. Only thing I got to work so far requires use of a temporary file: `exe '!ls | fzf >/tmp/foo ' | exe 'vsplit ' . system('cat /tmp/foo')` .... might be cleaner solution than that but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `fzf` needs access to the console, you will need to run it as a foreground command and there isn't really a good way for you to do that *and* capture the output from `fzf` (the filename) in Vim through a pipe. So using a temporary file to store the filename is the easiest approach here.

A simple solution is:

```
function! SelectFile()
  let tmp = tempname()
  execute '!ls | fzf >'.tmp
  let fname = readfile(tmp)[0]
  silent execute '!rm '.tmp
  execute 'vsplit '.fname
endfunction
```

Then use it with:

```
:call SelectFile()
```

(Or create a key mapping or a user command for it.)

Using the Vim `:terminal` to run `fzf` inside it (instead of shelling out with `:!`) is also a good option.

In any case, the real best approach here is to just use one of the excellent Vim plug-ins, either the simple bare-bones one which is included with [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) itself and probably also the more complete [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) which builds on the low-level plug-in to deliver powerful features you'll benefit from having around.

Comment: I ended up installing `ctrlp.vim`.

Comment: @testoflow Yeah that'll work... But I wonder why you didn't go with fzf.vim since you seem to already have the `fzf` binary around and that's usually the hardest part of setting it up...

Comment: I don't know, it seemed lighter to me